# If string is preceded by pattern of numbers and colons

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to Python and I've been trying to work out how to use if statements where it looks if a particular string is preceded by a certain pattern.

For example, the text in particular

`Sep 09 07:54:28 INFO: line of text here`

I have multiple lines like this in a file that I have my script reading from. The dates and times change on every line so I can't specify that text exactly.

I'm trying to replace the word `INFO` with something else.

However, the word `INFO` is scattered throughout the text file and I don't want to replace every instance of it.

I only want to replace `INFO` if it's preceded by `number number, colon, number number, colon, number number`.

So I've used `if` statements, `string.replace(old, new)` and I've been reading about 'positive lookbehind assertions' eg. `(?<=abc)def`

But I'm unsure how to specify a pattern of text, rather than specifying the exact text.

Just need pointing in the right direction! Thanks

EDIT: I should also point out that there are other instances of `INFO` that is preceded by a number, so I didn't want to make the rule simply 'be preceded by a number'. It will need to be specifically that pattern (xx:xx:xx)

EDIT2: Putting another example here to clarify further based on a comment

```
Sep 09 07:54:28 INFO: line of text here that contains many words

line of text that also contains the word INFO in the same line

Sep 09 07:56:30 INFO: line of text here that also contains many words

121334234: line of text here that contains INFO as well
```

I want replace the word INFO, but only on lines that have the time in that format (num, num, colon, num num, colon, num num)

EDIT 3:

```
with open(infile) as f:
    f = f.read()

with open(infile, 'r') as IN, open('output.html', 'w') as OUT:
    f = re.sub(r'(?<=\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s*INFO\b', ' INFO2', f)
```

this isn't returning any error but it doesn't perform any action

EDIT 4:

```
OUT.write(re.sub(r'(?<=\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s*INFO\b', ' INFO2', f))
```

Now this does replace INFO with INFO2 but it also stops all the code below it from working. But it's dependent on where I place the code. If I place it after all of my other code, it doesn't seem to do anything, if I place it straight after where I define my IN and OUT then it breaks all formatting from the code below it

Comment: post a more extended input sample and expected output

Comment: EDIT: just put it into the original question so it's clearer

Comment: don't post input text into comments - move it to the question with formatting

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following approach:

```
import re

s = '''Sep 09 07:54:28 INFO: line of text here that contains many words

line of text that also contains the word INFO in the same line

Sep 09 07:56:30 INFO: line of text here that also contains many words

121334234: line of text here that contains INFO as well'''
repl_str = 'new_info'   # sample replacement string

s = re.sub(r'(?<=\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s*INFO\b', f' {repl_str}', s)
print(s)
```

The output:

```
Sep 09 07:54:28 new_info: line of text here that contains many words

line of text that also contains the word INFO in the same line

Sep 09 07:56:30 new_info: line of text here that also contains many words

121334234: line of text here that contains INFO as well
```

Comment: Is there a way to roll this into an if statement? For example, if `?<=\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s*INFO\b` is found then replace?

Comment: @samrb, `re.sub` itself will do replacement only IF the pattern is found. There is no benefit of doing `if (re.search(pattern, s)): s = re.sub(repl, s)`

Comment: I've updated my original post with EDIT3 with my application of your code and the behaviour I'm getting

Answer (score 0):

A simple regex like

```
(?<=\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\s)INFO
```

would find all such INFO strings

Comment: This is looking like the kind of thing I was after. So \d represents a digit and \s represents a string? Is that there because there is a space between the xx:xx:xx and INFO?

Comment: @samrb \s represents whitespace

Comment: How do I roll this into an if statement?

`if "INFO" in line: OUT.write(line.replace('INFO:', '<strong><span style="color: #F5A422;">INFO:</span></strong>') + '\n')` I've tried putting those brackets before the INFO in the if and it says invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can find the pattern without using `positive lookbehind assertions` as well. Assuming that your file name is `test.txt`, you can do it as following-

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as reader:
    obj = re.compile(r'\d+\s+\d+:\d+:\d+\s+INFO')
    for line in reader:
        x = obj.search(line)
        if x:
            # do what you want to do
```

Comment: Seems like when I combine this with replace it says `AttributeError: 're.Match' object has no attribute 'replace'`